# How to calculate rotation value of 2 connected edges corner?

Tags: python

I can take 2 edges bisector angle value with middle = (theta1+theta2)/2, but I don't know how to calculate rotation value that direction is always outwards from the corner.
I need rotation value for rotating object from its 0,0,0 rotation.

Sometimes rotation is right and sometimes opposite, depending of the angle.

code: http://www.pasteall.org/60689

[image]

[image]

Comment: What I understand is that you're calculating what's labeled "Rotation angle" in the picture with (θ1+θ2)/2 and you want to find what's labeled "Object rotated". If that's the case, you just need to add pi (or 180°): ((θ1+θ2)/2)+π

Comment: This seems more suitable to a maths Stack Exchange. Is there something that is specific to blender in this question?